# How to handle database table for form with more than thirty fields?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

My question is not about code . Problem is I have to create form with more than 30 fields . I am thinking that I should create different tables for different portions of form . For Example one portion for sale orders and on portions for purchase orders and so on. But at the same time I feel that I will become complex when i will insert data or create relation with each other.
So, my second thought is  I should create only one table with 30 fields . But I don't know is it good practice? 
So, Please share your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was only ever going to make the one form and I knew it wasn't going to change frequently (or ever) then I may think about just setting up the fields as columns.

However, if you're going to have the potential of multiple forms and want to be able to change the fields frequently it might be a better approach to create (for example) a Form model which would store the basic information about the form and another FormField model so you could create each field as a relation to the form. You could add things like type to the FormField model and automatically generate the type of input required in your template.

You could then do something along the lines of creating a FormSubmission and FormFieldInput model to store the saved user input from submitting a form and view the data in a similar way to the way you rendered the form.

It's probably a bit of overkill unless you wanted the functionality of a form builder, automated configuration/rendering etc. You'll also end up with 30 rows of FormInput data for one form submission. Sometimes it makes sense, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally fine to use 30 fields in a form as well as 30 columns in a table.
Make sure to use the proper indexes on relevant columns and you should be good to go.